# How to type-hint a matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplots object in python3

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was wondering how is the "best" way to type-hint the axis-object of matplotlib-subplots.

running

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

f, ax = plt.subplots()
print(type(ax))
```

returns

```
<class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
```

and running

```
from matplotlib import axes
print(type(axes._subplots))
print(type(axes._subplots.AxesSubplot))
```

yields

```
<class 'module'>
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.axes._subplots' has no attribute 'AxesSubplots'
```

So far a solution for type-hinting that works is as follows:

```
def multi_rocker(
                 axy: type(plt.subplots()[1]), 
                 y_trues: np.ndarray,
                 y_preds: np.ndarray,
                 ):
  """
  One-Vs-All ROC-curve:
  """
  fpr = dict()
  tpr = dict()
  roc_auc = dict()
  n_classes = y_trues.shape[1]
  wanted = list(range(n_classes))
  for i,x in enumerate(wanted):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_trues[:, i], y_preds[:, i])
    roc_auc[i] = round(auc(fpr[i], tpr[i]),2)
  extra = 0
  for i in range(n_classes):
    axy.plot(fpr[i], tpr[i],)
  return
```

And the problem with it is that it isn't clear enough for code-sharing

Comment: I'm not sure what best practice is here, but if the issue is just clarity for code-sharing, who about `axy: type(plt.axes())`? it's slightly less convoluted. However I'm not that well versed in type-hinting and presume there is a cleaner/better way to do this

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As described in [Type hints for context manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57463477/type-hints-for-context-manager) :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_func(ax: plt.Axes):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.axes as mpl_axes

def multi_rocker(
                 axy: mpl_axes.Axes, 
                 y_trues: np.ndarray,
                 y_preds: np.ndarray,
                 ):
```

Comment: downvote because no explanation just code